# Humanoid hummingbird

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, anatomy

I was wondering what anatomy would allow a humanoid creature, where the height of the body is around 4 feet tall, to be able to fly like a hummingbird.

I have read that scaling up a hummingbird even by a little may not be possible as they are constantly flapping their wings and adding more mass would consume too much energy.

As this is an alien creature its musculoskeletal system can be anything to achieve hummingbird like flight, it must be similar to life on earth, so nothing too exotic in its chemistry or mechanisms and the humanoid body will have arms with the wings placed behind them or in an appropriate place.

Is this possible at all and if so how can it be done?

Comment: Even plain old non-hovering flappy flight doesn't scale up at all well, let alone something much more energetic and complex like hovering flight. Look at the differences in flying styles between vultures and songbirds.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I really wanted it to have the range of flighting angles and precision as a hummingbird for hand to hand combat mid air, big wings wouldn't allow this to happen as I imagined.

Comment: Flying in the manner of a hummingbird, no way; the way the wings of a hummingbird generate lift doesn't scale up to such size. Flying in general, just *maybe*, but only if the requirement of having a human shape is greatly relaxed -- humans arms are waaaay too short to function effectively as wings. For example, the heaviest eagles ([Haast's eagle](Haast's_eagle), extinct in historical times) weighed up to 15 kg (33 lb) or so and had a wingspan of 2.5 to 3 meters (8 to 10 ft). (15 kg is not far from the expected weight of a human-shaped creature 1.2 meters tall.)

Comment: @AlexP its wings would be separate and can be designed in any way or size, it will have separate human arms placed in the normal position also.

Comment: The problem is that the physics of lift generation doesn't scale up to such a large creature. The way hummingbirds fly is sort-of halfway between the way insects fly and the way "normal" birds fly.

Comment: @AlexP yeah, I was hoping that wasn't the case and there could be some way or different wing design to get around that.

Comment: This reminds me of [Toothiana](https://riseoftheguardians.fandom.com/wiki/Toothiana).

Comment: @Renan add Liu Kang styled bicycle kicks is it basically is lol

Comment: See Carnival Row... https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489974/

Comment: @castlewrks oh nice, how have I not seen this yet, it looks ace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As any mechanical designer knows, if you want to increase the frequency of an oscillatory motion, you need to reduce the oscillating masses.

This is why the hummingbird is to little: with bigger masses in its wings, it could not be capable of flipping them back and forth as it does.

Since the bio-mechanics you want to emulate is that one, the only way is to make the humanoid of a similar scale.

Comment: It is just barely possible that a creature larger than a hummingbird could hover. But not through the means they use. And probably not as agilely (only hummingbirds can fly backwards), accurately, nor for as long. And also, not a lot larger. Certain larger birds can briefly hover. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_flight#Hovering

Answer (score 1):

The idea of humanoid birds is not impossible considering birds evolved from bipedal Theropod dinosaurs with long arms and grasping hands. 
[image]
Natural selection could definitely have lead to an upright posture in some theropod Dinosaurs which could have allowed them to have a humanoid appearance.

[image]

However I do not believe that a humanoid anatomy would support the type of locomotion that is required for flight.